# Animate element to make it wider and taller by scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, height, width

I want to make the title (class title) of my page appear to be flattened into a bar (class scrollToTop) at the top of the screen when you scroll past it. Right now I am using code that makes the bar (a textless link with background color) appear when I pass the title but I would like to make it slowly appear as I scroll through the title. To clarify, it would start to appear (with the width of the title and minimal height) when the title reaches the top of the screen and finish appearing (with the final height and 100% width) once the title is completely offscreen. I would also like it to do the reverse when scrolling back up.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#top" class="scrollToTop"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var startY = $('.title').position().top + $('.title').outerHeight();
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                checkY();
            });

            function checkY(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > startY ){
                    $('.scrollToTop').slideDown();
                }else{
                    $('.scrollToTop').slideUp();
                }
            }
            checkY();
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks and let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/pH7u5/ ? The basic idea is to place the "textless bar link" below the header and fix to the top using CSS:

```css
.title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  /* style options here */
}

.scrollToTop {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  /* style options here */
}
```

When the header scrolls past, the "textless bar link" is shown, but it is below the header:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var offset = $(".title").offset();
    var posY = offset.top - $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".scrollToTop").css("visibility", posY <= 0 ? "visible" : "hidden");
}).trigger("scroll");
```

Only once the header is off screen far enough, the link becomes visible, appearing as if the header is shrunk to that height. The JSFiddle includes CSS to comment in, so you can see more easily how this works.

If you need more complex handling I recommend looking at [Scroll to Fixed](http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed) first. You should be able to mimic the effect you want by applying it to `.scrollToTop` and again moving it behind the header element.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While I didm't explain it very clearly above, I would also like the sticky header to expand across the width of the screen as I scroll down through the title. It would start out with a width of 20% of the screen and as you scroll expand to 100% width. Could you help with that too? Either way thanks again.

Comment: Easy: `var tweak = 50;  var widthPerc = Math.max(0, Math.min(100, -posY * tweak / 100)); $(".scrollToTop").css("width", widthPerc + "%");`. Add this to the scroll-event listener. It basically uses the remaining width to top of the header element and calculates a percentage from that. Use tweak to set how early/fast it should expand. I haven’t worked out the logic, so I called it `tweak`.